# Assigning tasks to specific machines with airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Airflow.

I have a DAG which contains a task that should run on a specific machine (EMR cluster in my case). How can I tell airflow where to run specific tasks so that every time it will run it will do so on that machine only?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run your worker on that machine with a [queue](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/celery.html#queues) name. In the airflow cli you could do something like:

```
airflow worker -q my_queue
```

Then define that task to use that queue:

```py
task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task',
    python_callable=my_callable,
    queue='my_queue',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: would running `airflow worker -q my_queue` take advantage of all processors on that cluster? or do you need to run multiple `airflow worker` commands

Comment: I think you would need to start a worker on each individual box, at least if using Celery. If using Mesos I'm not sure.

Comment: suppose I add another `airflow worker` to the mix, do I need to edit `celeryd_concurrency` in the airflow.cfg if I add a worker with more than the previously defined concurrency value?  Or could I simply override it with `airflow worker -c 12` (if I load up a box with 12 concurrent threads)

Comment: additionally -- suppose I have 5 independent tasks that lead to another task (i.e., 5 independent chains of A->B).  if I run them with `CeleryExecutor` with `concurrency = 4`, none of tasks B will start until all of tasks A finish.  That means that 4 threads will work on task A; when they're done, three threads will sit idle while another thread will work on task A. once all finish, they get to task B. any ideas about this?

Comment: Please ask questions as actual questions, and not in comments. The questions and answers here in a comment chain will not easily be found by someone with the same issue.

Comment: is it possible to have dynamic queue name like queue='{{ ti.xcom_pull("provide_queue_name") }}' ?

Comment: @jhnclvr, I can see below line in documentation.
queue (str) – which queue to target when running this job. Not all executors implement queue management, the CeleryExecutor does support targeting specific queues.
Why is that there?