# How to run airflow script after previous airflow script is complete?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I know that for example if we have several sql files in the data folder we can set priorities like script1 >> script2 in the end.
However, can we set priorities of other airflow scripts which are actually in the dag folder?

Answer (score 2):

Those are not priorities, those are execution order. If you want a particular DAG to execute first then just set it at an earlier execution time than other DAGs.

`script1 >> script2` means that script1 executes first and only then script2 executes.

You can try to artificially enforce priority by assigning a specific DAG to a [named queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186335/assigning-tasks-to-specific-machines-with-airflow) where it is the only DAG that executes in that named queue. Other than that there is no explicit way to have priority for entire DAGs.

For an Operator inside a DAG however you can use the `priority_weight` parameter in the `BaseOperator`.

Comment: Thanks Medhdeep that makes sense!