# Live changing worker queue in Apache Airflow

Tags: message-queue, airflow, airflow-scheduler

In Apache Airflow, I can [specify the worker queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186335/assigning-tasks-to-specific-machines-with-airflow/43217453#43217453) upon starting the worker.

I have a use case where I would like to change the queue the worker is using live so that the existing worker will pull new jobs from that queue.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no. You can launch a worker with `airflow worker -q <queue>`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to kill that worker, or interact with it at all once it's spawned.